# a lot of customization of front and back end and after if there are a lot of users, will slow down the server? if so, what do you recommend?

Tags: plugins, customization, javascript, database, users

I am currently building a platform on WordPress and am concerned about whether it will slow down when the number of users increases to over 1000 or when I add custom features. However, it might not be the case, so I'm writing to seek advice. Additionally, I would like flexibility in both the front and backend, as I may need to customize them later. Since I'll have to continually update and upgrade the platform long-term, I believe some space would be required. Furthermore, I would like to develop an app or make it more cost-effective after creating the website. I would appreciate some answers. I also want to know if there is flexibility in configuring the front end and back end and how much coding is required.

thanks,

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague, so it's not really possible to answer. The performance impact of lots of users or of customisations depends entirely on what the users are doing and what kinds of customisations you're making, as well as what optimisations you have in place.